# Javascript: How to make a custom context menu with copy/paste options

Tags: javascript

We're making a custom context menu for our online text editor. It's only nature to have copy/paste options inside. However we found out it's difficult to access system clipboard from within the browser. A few years ago it seemed impossible: [Custom Context Menu with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027805/custom-context-menu-with-javascript)

Still, google managed to do it in google docs, without the help of flash or special plugins, and it's working in both chrome and Firefox as far as I know. I'm wondering what they use to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Event handler on the right click mouse button that contains a preventDefault(), so that the standard menu is not shown. Same function trigegrs a render of a menu next to the current position of the mouse pointer.

Comment: your question is how make custom context menu or how get access to clipboard?

Comment: It's about how to access the clipboard

Comment: https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: Ironically it doesn't allow paste

Comment: Surely paste is the easier part of the process? Capture the copied data using the `success` event and then do what you like with it.

Comment: But then the user needs to trigger the paste event, like pressing ctrl-v or using paste in the vanilla context menu? In that case doesn't it defeats the purpose of a customized context menu?

Answer (score 2):

After some more research, I figured the feature works in Chrome, but not in firefox(mistake in my question). A popup would show up instructing the user to use shortcut instead: 
[image: A Dialog showing incompatibility with browsers suggesting key shortcuts be used as a workaround, for a mac]

So it seems like Google uses Google Docs Offline extension to provide this function. If the extension is disabled, it will prompt you to install Google Drive app.

So sadly there's no universal solution for this.

The following conversation is a few years old, but still holds the truth:

[How to paste on click? It works in google docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470272/how-to-paste-on-click-it-works-in-google-docs)

[javascript cut/copy/paste to clipboard: how did Google solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658282/javascript-cut-copy-paste-to-clipboard-how-did-google-solve-it/9658362#9658362)

[Adding copy & paste functionalities to a custom menu of a webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699747/adding-copy-paste-functionalities-to-a-custom-menu-of-a-webapp)

Comment: Thank you for the these resources. That was my exact thought process as well… “Why has no one solved this if I can do it in Google Docs”

Answer (score 1):

To render the menu, you can listen to the `contextmenu` event, which is triggered by right clicking. Then you can render a custom menu.

The **copy/paste** etc is probably done using `document.execCommand()`, which can be used to trigger copy/paste and such. Check your browser to see which commands are supported.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

```
// on right click, copy to clipboard.
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('contextmenu', function( event ) {
    // prevent the normal context menu from popping up
    event.preventDefault();
    // copy current selection
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

Comment: Seems like "paste" does not work in my browser(Chrome 56). From my search, seems like people usually use them in chrome extensions

Comment: `document.execCommand('paste');` works for me in IE11, so I'm afraid I can't help you with that one.

Answer (score 0):

*button with paste command on mousedown*

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('copy', function (ev) {
      ev.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', window.getSelection());
      ev.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

This should work on most browsers.